# How to Add Taxonomy description or other field value in a textarea with WYSIWYG?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, wysiwyg

I want a content editor to be able to create re-usable content, then have access to that content through the WYSIWYG editor when editing the node body or other text field. The idea is that the information gets used in multiple locations through the site, and they want to both cut down on copy/paste errors and only have to edit this information in one place.

The best analogy I can give here is, think of a hotel chain that has several properties each with it's own page, and they wish to have a table on each page that has the room description, occupancy, and price, and based on those parameters, they want to set the price for all properties listed on different pages at the same time.

I'm thinking taxonomy is the simplest way to create re-usable content, so the question is, is there a module that allows simple selection/insertion of a taxonomy description directly into say a table that's being edited with the WYSIWYG editor?

There will be hundreds of items I believe, so the interface should ideally be as simple as possible (like a taxonomy reference autocomplete widget).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add any [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module and enable it. Follow the installation instruction on your site (/admin/config/content/wysiwyg). You can use a wysiwyg editor like ckeditor. Then on same configuration page, for Filtered HTML select your editor.

Once an editor is set for a particular text format. You can follow these steps:

1. Add a Vocabulary to your taxonomy like Hotel Properties (hotel_properties). Edit it and add new fields to it like price.
2. Now in your content type, you can use Hotel Properties (hotel_properties) as term reference and widget type: autocomplete.
3. Now you can alter the node tpl or use [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) (Node Template) to display information from taxonomy.

**Note**: To get the wysiwyg editor, use filtered text editor.

Comment: The requirement is for the user to be able to insert the taxonomy term directly into the WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking taxonomy is the simplest way to create re-usable content, so the question is, is there a module that allows simple selection/insertion of a taxonomy description directly into say a table that's being edited with the WYSIWYG editor?

sounds like a job for:

#### [Editable Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields)

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g.
> at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It
> also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected,
> you can select editable (or click to edit).

**[Video tutorial/demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf_2e_RYS2M)**

Comment: This module doesn't really look like it works with a WYSIWYG. Can you confirm it does for D7, and if so, which WYSIWYG?

Comment: @Webdrips give me a few mins to double check on that.

Comment: @Webdrips [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v34Hi.jpg) using [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor). I am sure it should work with any wysiwyg module. As long as you have the format (ie: Filter HTML) to use the wysiwyg it should load. Also, I recommend you use the dev version of EditableFields.

Comment: I also recommend you use the [Better formats module](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats). So you can tell your field to only use a certain format, or re-order the format order.